# update wordpress database with php

Tags: php, database, wordpress

i am trying to update my wordpress database when button "btn-upddb" is clicked.
my php code:

```
if(isset($_POST['btn-upddb'])){
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->update(
        $wp_uwp_usermeta,
        array( 
            'user_volume' => '1500'
       ),
       array(
        'user_id' => '1'
    )
);
}
```

the html code is:

```
<form method="post">
<input name="btn-upddb" type="submit" value="update database" />
</form>
```

i tried the php code and the html code in the top and i am expecting to update the table wp_uwp_usermeta

Comment: Ok...and what happened instead? What debugging have you done? Remember we cannot run this code ourselves, or see your data etc

Comment: how can i debug it ?

Comment: https://www.atatus.com/blog/debugging-in-php/ has a simple guide to debugging with PHP, to get you started.

Comment: is `$wp_uwp_usermeta` defined? normally it goes `$wpdb->update($table, $data, $where, $format, $where_format);`

Answer (score 1):

You are not using a correct name for your table name, you can use something like this for your table name :

```
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'wp_usermeta';
```

and then you can use the correct table name in your codes.

This below command shows your dynamic prefix :

```
$wpdb->prefix
```